# Running tests using NUnit3 Console

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm trying to run tests via the command line using the NUnit Console Runner:
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Runner

I have installed https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.ConsoleRunner/ `NUnit.ConsoleRunner` in my NuGet

I have opened up the command line location in `\sanitized\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1`.  I run my test using the command `NUNIT3-CONSOLE myTests.dll` as mentioned in https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line

But I get the error:

> NUNIT3-CONSOLE: command not found

What command should I use?

> Note: This is a .netcore application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NUnit Console is currently unavailable for .net core:

> NUnit Console is compiled using the full .NET Framework and does not
>   currently support .NET Core. To run .NET Core tests from the command
>   line, you need to use dotnet test. For info on how to do this, see
>   https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard
>
> We are looking at creating a .NET Core based console runner, but it is
>   still in the planning stages.

Source: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/487

Just use `dotnet test` as described in nunit wiki.

Comment: Oh no!  I did not know that.  But `dotnet test` perfectly   I didn't need the `.` though  Thanks @Peska